# Как разделить строку в Python с сохранением разделителя?

Tags: python

Есть строка `привет\n\nземля`. Хочу разделить строку по разделителю `\n`.

```
z = text.split('\n')
```

на выходе получается

```
привет
\n
земля
```

а мне нужно

```
привет
\n
\n
земля
```

То есть чтобы дублирующий разделитель не удалялся

Comment: Почему разделено в трех местах, хотя разделитель встречается два раза?

Comment: Но на выходе получается `['привет', '', 'земля']`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Используйте [str.splitlines([keepends])](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.splitlines) с флагом `keepends=True`, тогда разделители останутся:

```
text = 'привет\n\nземля'
print(text.splitlines(keepends=True))
# ['привет\n', '\n', 'земля']
```

**UPD.** Немного доработки для разделения `\n` от элементов:

```
text = 'привет\n\nземля'
lines = []
for line in text.splitlines(keepends=True):
    if len(line) > 1 and line.endswith('\n'):
        lines.extend([line[:-1], '\n'])
    else:
        lines.append(line)

print(lines)
# ['привет', '\n', '\n', 'земля']
```

Comment: блин, а он  у первого слова остался

Comment: а надо чтобы каждый был как отдельный элемент

Comment: @Radzhab, обновил ответ

Answer (score 5):

Через регулярные выражения:

```
import re

text = 'привет\n\nземля'
parts = re.findall(r'(\n|.+)', text)
print(parts)  # ['привет', '\n', '\n', 'земля']
```