# Добавить \n в массив

Tags: python, массивы, строки

Всем привет. Допустим у меня есть строка `'apples \n bananas'`. При попытке применить к ней метод split() получается `['apples', 'bananas']`, как сделать так, что бы \n тоже оказался в массиве,т е `['apples','\n', 'bananas']`

Comment: `'apples \n bananas'.split(' ')`

Comment: @S.Nick не работает :(

Comment: не понимаю как это может не работать, а что говорит?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как разделить строку в Python с сохранением разделителя?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1081628)

Answer (score 4):

```
Python 3.5.3 (default, Sep 27 2018, 17:25:39) 
[GCC 6.3.0 20170516] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'apples \n bananas'.split(" ")
['apples', '\n', 'bananas']
```

Просто в метод split() нужно передать знак пробела (" " или ' ', без разницы).